# Safely fit new bathroom pull switch to existing wiring

Tags: electrical, bathroom, switch

We moved into a house that has a bathroom pull switch (surface mount box - is that a 'pattress'?) dangling from the ceiling by a couple of inches of wires. I think when we moved in it was flush with the ceiling and I can only assume it had been glued on (there are no existing holes in the plaster) - the glue only lasted a few weeks at most.

In addition to dangling, the switch itself only works intermittently, so I've bought a replacement switch from homebase and want to fit it.

So my question is this. How do I fit the box without drilling through the existing wires? I have somewhere on of those staple-gun shaped current/metal detectors, but it's always been a bit rubbish at the best of times and given the small diameter of the base plate I don't think it would be accurate enough to tell me where I can and cannot drill anyway.

Alternatively, would I be better off gluing it (e.g. 'no more nails')? Or will that just come off again after a few days or weeks?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm in the UK by the way - so answers would have to be specific to UK regulations etc.